# warble compiled war not compiling sources that use ruby 1.9 language features

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, warbler

I have a jruby on rails app that is written using ruby 1.9 syntax.  When I try to run warble compiled war, warbler only spits out .class files for ruby files that don't make use of the new language features in ruby 1.9, such as the new hash syntax {foo: bar}.  I have config.webxml.jruby.compat.version = "1.9" in my config/warbler.rb and JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9.  Am I missing something?

I also commented on a related bug on github:
https://github.com/jruby/warbler/issues/72#issuecomment-5665639

Has anyone successfully compiled a jruby rails app with warbler that uses ruby 1.9?

Answer (score 1):

warbler bug, here's a pull request that addresses the issue:
https://github.com/jruby/warbler/pull/99

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is due to a trivial bug in warbler that causes it to always compile in 1.8 mode.  A fix has been proposed here:
http://kenai.com/jira/browse/WARBLER-28